# “php -f” doesn’t run code but only shows file contents

Tags: linux, command-line, php

Running Debian 9 and PHP 7.3, trying to execute a file with the `php -f hello.php` command. Instead of echoing `hello` it outputs the source code. The full code is

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
echo 'hello';
?>
```

What I did:

- Confirmed the file has read and execute permissions.
- Confirmed the PHP [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line is correct.
- Confirmed that PHP CLI tools are installed.

What is wrong? How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When PHP parses a file, it looks for opening and closing tags, which are `<?php` and `?>` which tell PHP to start and stop interpreting the code between them. Parsing in this manner allows PHP to be embedded in all sorts of different documents, as everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser.
>
> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the `short_open_tag` `php.ini` configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the `--enable-short-tags` option).

<sup>([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php))</sup>

So the most reliable solution is to use `<?php` instead of `<?` in your code.

Comment: I did what you suggested and i am not getting the output hello :( Also short open tag is enabled, but I edited the script to use the <?php just to try it.

Comment: @Lid What exactly are you getting? I am getting `hello` (on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS). There is no trailing newline though (because you didn't use one), so if there was `\r` (carriage return) in my `PS1` then I might not see `hello` because it would be overwritten instantly. For now I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: that is so weird, ok on windows it puts the output automatically below the command prompt, on unix if I don't specify a \n it does hellouser@localhost:~#

Comment: @Lid That’s just a side effect of how Windows linefeeds virus Linux (and even macOS) linefeeds work.

Answer (score 2):

That “shebang” is not needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Just make your script this; note you should add the `php` to the opening short tag (`<?`):

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
?>
```

Then run it like this:

```
php -f hello.php
```

Or even just leave out the `-f` and run it like this:

```
php ./hello.php
```

And then the output would be this:

```
hello
```

Additionally, when you say this:

> - Confirmed the file has read and execute permissions.

PHP files do not have to have execute permissions; only read permissions since the file will be read and parsed by the PHP interpreter. Same for the command line as well as the Apache module PHP interpreter.